# Polymer binding not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm seeing an issue where I can see the bound 'test' value appear on the demo page on Chrome but not in Firefox. I'm already including the polyfills (webcomponents-lite.js) so I'm really not sure what's missing. Any ideas?? Thank you in advance.

ticket-item demo page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>ticket-item demo</title>
    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-snippet.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../ticket-item.html">

    <script>
      window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
        let element = document.getElementById('ticket-item');
        element.test = 'test';
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic ticket-item demo</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>
          <ticket-item id="ticket-item"></ticket-item>
        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

ticket-item element

```
<dom-module id="ticket-item">
  <template>
    <style include="my-theme">
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <div>test: [[test]]</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class TicketItem extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'TicketItem'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          test: String
        };
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(TicketItem.is, TicketItem);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing:

> **Custom element names**. By specification, the custom element's name **must start with a lower-case ASCII letter and must contain a dash (-)**. There's also a short list of prohibited element names that match existing names. For details, see the [Custom elements core concepts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements-core-concepts) section in the HTML specification.

So, you must change the name of "item" element.

Instead of loading the `webcomponents-lite.js` directly, load `webcomponents-loader.js` (a client-side loader that dynamically loads the minimum polyfill bundle, using feature detection), that will do the rest.

[Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8337av?p=preview): works both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thank you very much Ofisora for taking the time to add an example in plnkr.
I had purposely renamed references to my component to 'item' in this post only, just to make it more obscure, but as you pointed out that's incorrect so I've changed it to avoid confusion. Thanks for the note on naming convention, though.

The strange thing is that I looked at your example and do see it working in FF, and when I copy the exact same code to my local, it still doesn't work for me in FF. It's very strange. I'm going to try to maybe re-create the element and see if that helps.

Comment: wow... I found the issue... the problem was that I named my component 'ticket-item' and the id was set to 'ticket-item'. It apparently needs to be something different from 'ticket-item'. I change the id to 'item' and now I'm seeing the binding!

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer too because it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I named my component 'ticket-item' and the id was set to 'ticket-item'. It apparently needs to be something different from 'ticket-item'. I change the id to 'item' and now I'm seeing the binding.

Comment: Additionally, I think that your is() function should be `{ return 'ticket-item'; }`, not `{ return 'TicketItem'; }`.